# Evaluating $\int\frac{1}{1+3\cos^2 x}dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I got this fairly simple looking problem 
$$\int\frac{1}{1+3\cos^2 x}dx$$
Although it looks simple enough but I am stuck on how to begin a hint might be enough to solve this problem. What I tried was that changing $\cos^2 x$ to $\sin^2 x$ $$\int\frac{1}{1+3(1-\sin^2 x)}dx$$
I don't know what else to do. Any formula that I am missing here? I did try some half angle formula for $\cos x$ but it was making things bit messy because of square, simplest hint must be enough for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is directly from Wolfram Alpha.

[image: Solution]

Comment: oh dear , so simple thanks a lot i was confused about starting

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way: Perform the Weierstrass substitution on the cosine term, comes out beautifully.

Comment: What is "the Weierstrass substitution"?  Do you mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution?  (According to the article, it is not due to Weierstrass.)